# Multi-tenancy in Kyma

Tags: multi-tenant, kyma

Could you please help me to understand how we can achieve multi tenancy using Kyma?
If we want to migrate our existing cloud applications we need to support multi tenancy as they all supports it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special support for multitenancy in Kyma. It is up to application developer to decide what pattern to use. You can have multitenancy on infrastructure layer (kubernetes cluster per customer), or on application layer (single instance but separate storage for customers). Separate cluster per customer is the default solution for enterprise customers. For smaller customers, you share infrastructure usually.